# Rails ActiveAdmin - get current_admin_user in utility navigation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The ActiveAdmin docs say that I can override the utility navigation like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info", html_options: { target: :blank }
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu # can also pass priority & html_options for link_to to use
    end
  end
end
```

It also says that the default display includes the current user's email address.  How does it get the current user's email address?  When I try replacing the `menu.add label` value with `current_admin_user` I get an error that says `current_admin_user` is undefined.  How do I access info about the currently signed in user from the config file?  How does ActiveAdmin do it behind the scenes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
config.namespace :admin do |admin|
      admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
         menu.add  :label  => proc{ display_name current_active_admin_user },
                  :url    =>  proc{  edit_admin_admin_user_path(current_active_admin_user) }  ,#link_to current_active_admin_user,
                  :id     => 'current_user',
                  :if     => proc{ current_active_admin_user? }
        admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
      end
    end
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.  Can you explain why it works behind the scenes and why I might have been getting the error I was getting?

Comment: it works because of using procs which are called in needed context, so that current_admin_user is defined in moment of proc invocation

Comment: Ok, cool thanks.  Also a kind of unrelated q - if a block is a proc (to my understanding), why can I not pass in a block, e.g. `:if => { current_active_admin_user? }` and skip the `proc` in front of it?  What exactly does the `proc` in front of it do?

Comment: because manu.add should have  hash argument, you can't store blocks in hash elements, only objects, which is Proc is. Anonymous block can be send only for lsat parameter... I think you should read this http://www.snowfrog.net/2011/08/30/ruby-blocks-and-procs/

Comment: Just to point out, the url part should be **edit_admin_admin_path** instead of **edit_admin_admin_user_path**.

Answer (score 3):

Just try the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      menu.add label: "ActiveAdmin.info", url: "http://www.activeadmin.info",
                                      html_options: { target: :blank }
      admin.add_current_user_to_menu  menu
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
    end
  end
end
```